# Show that the code below runs in Θ(nlogn) time

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, analysis

This is a homework question and I really need help on this one and I hope somebody helps me out with it

> We have n electric light bulbs, with labels from 1 to n. The light
>   bulbs are all turned OFF initially. Each light bulb has a switch, so
>   that flipping the switch will change its status from ON to OFF, or
>   from OFF to ON. At the i-th round, for i=1,2,....,n we will flip the
>   switches of those light bulbs whose labels are a multiple of i, and we
>   are interested to know which light bulbs will be ON after the n-th
>   round.
>
> We can compute the final status of each light bulb using the following
>   code:
>
> ```
> Intialize A[1...n] so that each entry is OFF;
> for(round i=1,2,...,n) {
>   for (position j=i,2i,3i,...){
>     if(j<=n) Flip A[j];
>     else break;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 1. Show that the obove code runs in O(n^2) time
> 2. Show that the above code runs in Θ(nlogn) time.
> 3. Design a faster algotithm that can compute the final status in O(n) time.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Do you have any thoughts about the questions..

Comment: What point do you have trouble with? To show that it runs in O(n^2), as the title of your question suggests? That one should be easy, if you remember that that's an _upper_ bound.

Comment: @Haris Well I did try to compute the time function but cannot find a way to do so. I know if I can compute a time function I can just use Induction to prove the things.

Comment: @tobias_k I edited the question, its the Θ(nlogn) part I am having a trouble with. I just need a little push in the right direction.

Comment: You need to find the lower bound, Ω(n) and use the fact that the code is O(n^2) to prove Θ(nlogn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every `i` from `1` to `n`, the inner loop runs in `Θ(n / i)` time. Thus the whole running time is `Θ(n / 1 + n / 2 + ... + n / n)`.

Now it only remains to use the well-known fact that `1 / 1 + 1 / 2 + ... + 1 / n = Θ(log(n))`. This completes parts 1 and 2 of your question.

For a faster algorithm, try to do the experiment for some small `n` (e.g. `n = 100`). What are the light bulbs that are turned ON in the end? What can you guess from the result? Finally, can you prove your guess?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you give me a link for the proof of 1 / 1 + 1 / 2 + ... + 1 / n = Θ(log(n)). I cannot seem to find a proof for this anywhere.

Comment: I googled and found this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series